# Add Printing feature in a class dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef

I am developing an Invoice Application.

I am using `MEF` to have a modular approach.

I have created a module (PlugIn) for Printing which Prints document to Printer.

Now, my question is

There is a class called Sales, once the user adds (Saves) a Sales. I need to check if the Printing module is installed, if So then I need to pass this Sales to Printer using that module.

I am not getting, how can I achieve this.

The idea I have is, I will use `[Import(typeof(IPrint))]` as a property in my Sales class, and if I have some value for this property then I will send the document to the Printer.

Is there a better approach for this requirement.

Comment: If you are using MEF then you know if it is loaded or not. Simply use bool IsPluginLoaded.

Comment: My Question is, let us say I myself doesn't have any interface for Printing in my application, but later some other programmer hired my client want to add the printing feature for my Sales class. How will he inject that after saving the Sales.

Comment: ok. Then you need make a method(fire_plugins) which will be fired when Sales.Save fired. On fire_plugins method you will fire the plugins needs to fired when Sales saved. Store your plugins in a List<MethodInfo>.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Could you post the code that imports plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are implementing you class. Try something like this:

```
//in your Metadata you should have bool FireOnSave
public class Sales
{
    IEnumerable<Lazy<T, TMetadata>> myPlugins;
    private static CompositionContainer _container;
    static Sales()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        var d = new DirectoryInfo(".\\");
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(d.FullName));
        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    }

    void ImportPlugins()
    {
         myPlugins = _container.GetExports<T, TMetadata>();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //do your saving work here
        fire_plugins();
    }

    private void fire_plugins()
    {
        foreach (var m in myPlugins)
        {
            if (m.Metadata.FireOnSave)
                m.Value.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.